# ReJson - Retrieve all values from matches of 2nd layer of keys

Tags: json, redis, redisjson

I am trying to get all values whose 2nd level key is same. Does ReJson Support this functionality?
For example:

`JSON.SET myKey . '{"book1": {"author":"xyz", "price":100}, "book2": {"author":"abc", "price":200}}'`

`JSON.GET myKey .book1.author` => `"\"xyz\""`

`JSON.GET myKey .book2.author` => `"\"abc\""`

Trying to fetch all author's values

`JSON.GET myKey ..author`

Getting the following error:

> (error) ERR Search path error at offset 2: an identifier can only begin with a letter, a dollar sign or an underscore - use bracket notation for anything else`

`JSON.OBJKEYS myKey .` => `1) "book1" 2) "book2"`

The doc says it does support JSON PATH.

Links:https://oss.redislabs.com/rejson/ https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, ReJSON does not provide that functionality yet.

The [docs](https://oss.redislabs.com/rejson/path/) say:

> ReJSON's syntax is a subset of common best practices and resembles JSONPath

Answer (score -2):

try:

```
json.mget myKey $..author
```

https://oss.redis.com/redisjson/commands/#jsonmget

Comment: 127.0.0.1:6379> JSON.SET myKey . '{"book1": {"author":"xyz", "price":100}, "book2": {"author":"abc", "price":200}}'

OK

127.0.0.1:6379> json.mget myKey $..author

1) "[\"xyz\",\"abc\"]"